# database structure for a mobile app, which is faster

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, azure, mobile

Maybe the question is a bit complex and complicated (that's why I need to make a brief introduction)
my team and I are developing a Mobile App with Node js. Now we are in the part of the database structure. Our idea is to do it in Azure SQL. But we have a couple of questions regarding the structure of the database.
We offer 5 services (at the moment), of which each user can be assigned several services (may non or all). Based on the services it has, the user will be redirected to a screen where all the services will be and only those assigned with color (to be able to click) and the others in gray (so that they cant click it)
Which is better, create one column per service or all services in a single column array style?
for example

service 1| service 2| service 3|service 4|service 5|
true     |   fasle |   true | true| false| true

or

service

[service 1,service 2,service 3,service 4,service 5]

Because I think that if in the future we have x services, going through the entire array and making a condition to verify what service it has is going to make the latency of the app to slow, instead hitting a certain column maybe makes it faster

I hope the question has been understood, sorry if the maries.
regards

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an azure SQL question but more of a relational database question.

In general you should avoid both these methods and try to [normalize](https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html) your database.

Your database knows how to query multiple databases without any performance hits, its made for it.

The best option in my experience is to create a many to many table connection

So one table that holds the original data without any mention of a service, Maybe called Entities

**Id, Data, Time, Active**

Another table that holds the relations to the services, called EntitiesToServices

**Id, ServiceId, OtherTableId**

And a third table that holds data about the services called Services

**Id, Name**

In this way you can expand all your services freely and add more tables without anyone interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a set of up to 64 true/false values, consider a single column of type `SET`.  Similarly you could some any sized `INT` (again with a limit of 64 flags) and turn on/off each 'service'.  Today you have 5; tomorrow, as you say, there will be more.

The syntax for `SET` is a bit clumsy.  So is using `INT` for this.

It is very compact; this may or may not be a bonus.

Normalizing (as mentioned in another answer) may be a better solution, especially if you need to store more than just on/off for each service for each user.

Please provide more details on what actions will happen with these flags; then we can get into more detail.